# Is return on a generator function still valid if you want to stop yielding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supposed I have this code:

```
def yield_values():
    if do_something():
        yield 1
        yield 2

    if not do_something_bad():
        yield 3
        return

    yield 4


def do_something():
    return True

def do_something_bad():
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_gen = yield_values()
    print(next(function_gen))
    print(next(function_gen))
    print(next(function_gen))
```

They say that mixing yield and return in a generator function is a bad idea.  But in my use case, if do_something_bad returns False already.. I wanted to yield 3 and exit so that the 4 is not yielded anymore.

Is this perfectly legal or should I do another way?

**Updated:  Added try/except**

```
def yield_values():
    if do_something():
        yield 1
        yield 2

    if not do_something_bad():
        yield 3
        return "something"

    yield 4


def do_something():
    return True

def do_something_bad():
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        function_gen = yield_values()
        print(next(function_gen))
        print(next(function_gen))
        print(next(function_gen))
        print(next(function_gen))
    except StopIteration as err:
        print("Error : ".format(err.value))
1
2
3
Error :
```

Comment: Ok thanks..I just read it somewhere in some random google hits maybe that I have come into.  I am still exploring Python so I just try to gather as much information on the things that I am reading

Comment: The code you've written *will have `None` there*. You have to `return <something>`

Comment: Tried that as well mate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. What version of Python are you on?

Comment: Python 3.7 is the version of my virtualenv. Posted again my whole code and the output

Comment: That's because your format string is broken, `"Error : ".format(err.value)` should be something like `"Error : {}".format(err.value)`

Comment: Ohhh jeez... thank you! Sorry for being a dummy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [return docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) it is absolutely legal:

> In a generator function, the return statement indicates that the
>   generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised. The
>   returned value (if any) is used as an argument to construct
>   StopIteration and becomes the StopIteration.value attribute.

Comment: Tried to wrap around a try and except but the StopIteration.value always return none even if I explicitly add return "something"

Comment: @MarkEstrada seems like an entirely unrelated issue, what code exactly are you using to try to catch the exception> If I put `return "something"` in the code you posted, the error comes with `"something"` as the `.value`

Comment: I wrap the whole __main__ function in the try except Stopiteration... and tried to print the .value

Comment: Please see my added info above my question.  I explicitly set the return "something"

Comment: @MarkEstrada I'm not sure why you even care since returning a value is not part of the original question. That aside, the problem of your test case is you use `.format` but you never put a format placeholder in your string, so `err.value` is put nowhere.

Comment: @MarkEstrada did you resolve the issue with the `StopIteration.value` i read the comments and hope the @juanpa.arrivillaga gave you the full help